# Nginx proxy_pass all non-api routes

Tags: nginx

My nginx setup needs to direct all non-`/api/` requests to `http://198.xxx.xxx.xx:8080/`. When I visit `/`, all is well. I can visit any of the routes provided by my front-end. However, when I hit refresh, the route is not found.

I realize that I could just add every route manually to `proxy_pass` to the root. Obviously this would be tedious. There must be a mistake or a better way to configure my nginx setup.

Here's my setup:

```
upstream app_server {
    server unix:/var/run/unicorn.sock fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
    listen   80;
    server_name xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.com;

    location ~* ^.+\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|zip|tgz|gz|rar|bz2|doc|xls|exe|pdf|ppt|txt|tar|mid|midi|wav|bmp|rtf|mp3|flv|mpeg|avi)$ {
            try_files $uri @app;
    }

    location ^~ /api/ {
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwaded_for;
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
            proxy_redirect off;
            proxy_pass http://app_server/api/;
    }

    location /about {
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
            proxy_redirect off;
            proxy_pass http://198.xxx.xxx.xx:8080/;
    }

    location / {
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
            proxy_redirect off;
            proxy_pass http://198.xxx.xxx.xx:8080/;
    }
}
```

When I visit `/about` and refresh the page, it correctly loads. But doing the same with any other route (excluding the root/home) gives a blank page and shows as a 404 in my server logs. How can I set all non-`/api/` paths to `proxy_pass` to `http://198.xxx.xxx.xx:8080/`?

Comment: For anyone finding this be aware that the config above has a misspelling. The `/api/` location has `proxy_add_x_forwaded_for` rather than `proxy_add_x_forwarded_for`

Comment: @david Thanks for the comment! Wish I'd seen that.

Comment: Oh dear, this was a year ago. Has it been like that the whole time?

Comment: @david Ha! I ended up rearranging some things in that project to get around this issue. Really wishing I'd noticed that now...

Answer (score 2):

I would try a bit different approach:

```
upstream app_server {
    server unix:/var/run/unicorn.sock fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name xxxxxxxx.com;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ @app;
    }

    location /api/ {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwaded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_pass http://app_server/api;
    }

    location @app {
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_pass http://198.xxx.xxx.xx:8080;
    }
}
```

So, here we specify the "catch-all" block to be @app, which forwards requests that don't match any filesystem file to the `198.xxx.xxx.xx:8080`.

Then we have a separate `location /api/` block, which matches all requests starting with URI `/api`. Those are then proxied to the `app_server`.

Comment: Hi Tero, I can't thank you enough for the answer and explanation. Seems like it should work. I'll give it a shot a little later and get back to you.

Comment: Unfortunately, when I run what you've written, I get the following error: `nginx: [emerg] "proxy_pass" cannot have URI part in location given by regular expression, or inside named location, or inside "if" statement, or inside "limit_except"` for the line `proxy_pass http://198.xxx.xxx.xx:8080/;`.

Comment: I updated the answer, nginx doesn't like ending slashes in `proxy_pass` directives.

Comment: I had been fiddling with this for my API section which now works a charm without any rewrites but I am still having an issue with the catchall.  I get 404 not founds if I try to access a route with a page refresh after accessing it normally through the the page